# How does Magento handle multiple stores on the same domain

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multidomain

I've been asked to scope out a move to multisite Magento, introducing a second store that uses a different currency and pricing.

However, we do not wish to redirect customers to a new URL to use the new site, only display the different pricing in the other store view when they choose the other store using the default store switcher.

Can Magento handle serving multiple stores from a single URL, or does it need some difference to render route properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Magento serve multiple stores from single URL.You don't need different url for each store view.

Yo can add stores in the admin menu System > Manage Stores.

> Then, in System > Configuration > Web > URL Options, change Add Store Code to URLs to "Yes".

Comment: So what you are saying is that it still requires a store code in the URL to differentiate between stores. I was hoping it was possible to have the store code stored in the session so that the store the user is in is 'invisible' apart from the changes they see on screen

Comment: store code is not mandatory